# Unable to download application from Google Play [Even though the said application was developed on the same device]

Tags: android, publish, google-play

I have developed and published an Android application on the Android market. The phone I used for developing this is a Samsung Galaxy running Android 2.3.

On Google Play, it does not allow me to download the app to the above phone, saying that the phone is not eligible.

What could be the cause of this ? It gets downloaded to other devices, that even run Android 2.2 so it can't be an issue with the Manifest.

Comment: Did you uninstall the application you developed ? Because the app on Google Play and the developed app have different signatures but the same package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifest can define other limitations (other than min version). For example screen size, density, required hardware and more.

The developer can also define some filters in the developer console.

So probably one of those options are filtering out your device.